# Convert a callback method into a Task

Tags: c#

In C#, is there a way to convert:

```
Foo(Action<T> onComplete);
```

Into:

```
Task<T> FooTask();
```

Foo function is part of an external library, and can't be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a job for [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.setresult?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskCompletionSource_1_SetResult__0_):

```
Task<T> FooAsync<T>()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    Foo(tcs.SetResult);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This allows a call-back based API to be consumed as a `Task` based API.

You can call like this:

```
var result = await FooAsync<YourType>();
```

`SetResult` completes the returned `Task`, and sets it's `Result` to the value passed into `Foo`'s call-back.

---

If `Foo` can throw an exception, then that should be handled explicitly and placed on the `Task` (rather than thrown immediately), to comply with async convention:

```
Task<T> FooAsync<T>()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    try
    {
        Foo(tcs.SetResult);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tcs.SetException(ex);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work as the `T` is passed into the `Action`, rather than returned from it (which would be `Func<T>` or `Func<T, T>`)?

Comment: @MartinCostello Yes, and that `T` would be passed into `SetResult`, which can be converted to `Action<T>`.

Comment: Starting with NET5 non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` is available, which may be useful for non-generic `Action`

Comment: @JL0PD Nice, that's better than having to use `TaskCompletionSource<object>` then `SetResult(null)`.